# How do I iterate over enum values in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, enums, iteration, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to find the best way to iterate over all of the values on an enum defined in Google Closure. Let's say I have the following enum defined:

```js
/**
 * @enum {number}
 */
sample.namespace.Fruit = {
  Orange: 0,
  Apple: 1,
  Banana: 2
};
```

Right now, the best way I've seen to do this would be something like this:

```js
for (var key in sample.namespace.Fruit) {
    var fruit = /** @type {sample.namespace.Fruit} */ (sample.namespace.Fruit[key]);
    // Make a smoothie or something.
}
```

I consider that painful to read. I'm listing a namespace three times just to get the compiler to come along for the ride. Is there another iteration technique that I should be using instead? Is this the best way to accomplish this form of iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `goog.object.forEach` to avoid namespace repetition.

```
goog.object.forEach(sample.namespace.Fruit,
                    function(value, key, allValues) {
                      // Make some delicious fruit jellies or something.
                    });
```

As a side note, in most cases you want to avoid using string keys for @enums so the compiler can rename those.

Comment: the compiler will not rename them if the key are real quoted strings though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **for loop** to iterate over your objects..

```
var obj = sample.namespace.Fruit;

for(var key in obj) {
    console.log("Fruit :: " + key + " -- " + obj[key])
}
```

​**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tVnsz/)**